# MYSQL Update Join Statement

Tags: mysql

Update: I made a mistake in the import. All my "Building" fields in companies had an extra question mark. Not sure how this happened. Anyway this is solved.

A newbie question, (Yes, I have tried for hours and hours to do this)

I am trying to update a database with two tables.

The tables look similar to this.

latlon3:

```
  id building roadno block  lat2   lon2
   1  1331     5943    3    35.55  54.55
```

Companies:

```
  id building roadno block latitude longitude
   1  1331     5843    3     empty    empty
```

Ok. So I need to update the companies table, from the latlon3 table, if all three conditions are true(This is a must). The Building, RoadNo, and Block. This is what I have so far:

```
 UPDATE companies t
 JOIN latlon3 a USING (Building, RoadNo, Block)
 SET t.latitude = a.lat2, t.longitude = a.lon2
 WHERE t.latitude = '' AND t.longitude = ''
```

It always shows zero rows affected. This is my problem. The table companies don't update with the corresponding latitude and longitude fields from latlon3 table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try whit lower case ... USING(building , roadno , block) ...

Comment: what is the output ouput of 
    SELECT * FROM companies WHERE t.latitude = '' AND t.longitude = '' ???

Comment: I just made everything lowercase, same problem.

Comment: and SELECT * FROM companies WHERE latitude = '' AND longitude = ''  have rows????

Comment: Hi. If I add the "t" in t.latitude. the error is:#1054 - Unknown column 't.latitude' in 'where clause' If I remove the "t". I get Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 144,495 total, Query took 0.0020 sec) [id: 1 - 30]

Comment: update the table structure in http://sqlfiddle.com/, so it will be easy for us check the result

Comment: Yes, inye. That has rows. Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 144,495 total, Query took 0.0190 sec) [id: 1 - 30]
SELECT *
FROM companies
WHERE latitude = ''
AND longitude = ''
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `roadno` value is different in the two tables. How is using `USING` in this field, there is no relationship between tuples, and so returns `0 rows affected`. I added the `id` in check

Try:

```
UPDATE companies t
 JOIN latlon3 a ON a.id=t.id SET t.latitude = a.lat2, t.longitude = a.lon2
 WHERE t.latitude = '' AND t.longitude = ''
```

Comment: This produces no result, zero rows affected. It is only when all three id's are the same that they need to update. Some of the values are the same.

Comment: @JohanFourie Try `WHERE t.latitude is NULL AND t.longitude is NULL`

Comment: Hi. Yours is updating. but I want to make sure what happened. ON a.id=t.id is not what I want. I want the Roadno, building, and block no to be the ones to correlate.

Comment: @JohanFourie `ON a.building=t.building AND a.roadno=t.roadno AND a.block=t.block` you'll get only `building = 1331`, `roadno = 5943` and `block = 3`. If any of these fields are different, as the post  `roadno = 5843` will not work. Make sure the structure of the database fields are equal.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 UPDATE companies t
 JOIN latlon3 a ON a.building=t.building AND a.roadno=t.roadno AND a.block=t.block  SET t.latitude = a.lat2, t.longitude = a.lon2
 WHERE t.latitude = '' AND t.longitude = ''
```

Comment: 0 rows affected. (Query took 5.4683 sec) :(